Kotlin/JS: `types` not included in generated package.json
Running jsBrowserProductionWebpack with generateTypeScriptDefinitions() set on js(IR) does not seem to include types in my package.json

Per the documentation you can add a custom field like so: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-project-setup.html#package-json-customization
kotlin {
    js {
        compilations["main"].packageJson {
            customField("types", "kotlin/your-module-name.d.ts")
        }
    }
}

